# Kendo ui grid client template "Id is not defined"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to use a edit command link for editing a row of kendo web ui grid. The problem is that I am not able to use the syntax **"#= Id #"**, Id being defined as **id** in model and one of the **fields**. Here is the schema defined in datasource

```
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        .....
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    RequesterName: { type: "string" },
                    ...
                }
            },
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        ...
        pageSize: 5
});
```

And the kendo grid

```
$("#request-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    ...
    columns: [{
        field: "Id", title: "Id", width: 35
    }, {
        field: "RequesterName", title: "Req Name", width: 175
    }, { 
    ...
    }, {
        command: [{ name: "edit", template: "<a href='@Url.Action("_SoftwareRequestEdit", "SoftwareRequest")" + "/#= Id #" + "'>Edit</a>" }]
    }],
    ...
});
```

With the above code, when the grid loads I get following javascript error

```
ReferenceError: Id is not defined
#11 http://localhost:49713/Admin/SoftwareRequest/SoftwareRequestList:3
#10 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:294:22 eval (eval at ()
#9 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:26361:44 Widget.extend._createButton()
#8 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:27571:38 Widget.extend._cellTmpl()
#7 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:27523:41 Widget.extend._tmpl()
#6 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:27624:37 Widget.extend._templates()
#5 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:25055:18 new Widget.extend.init()
#4 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:2785:25 HTMLDivElement.()
#3 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:381:23 Function.jQuery.extend.each()
#2 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js:137:17 jQuery.fn.jQuery.each()
#1 http://localhost:49713/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.web.js:2784:26 $.fn.(anonymous function) [as kendoGrid]
```

As you can see, I have defined **Id** in the model, but I am still getting **ReferenceError: Id is not defined**. Any clues for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables from the model can be used only for a template column, not for a command column.

Basically you can achieve your goal by using fully [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-action-links?) column, you do not have to use a command column.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for quite some time. Indeed the template column works nicely in this case. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your "#= Id #" part with "#= data.Id ? Id : ' ' #"